# Select a limited number from table, but all connected from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a SQL project and I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a table called Recipes, and a table called Products, and one called RecipeProducts. All recipe's have their own ID, and all products have their own ID. In Recipeproducts is the recipeID and ProductID stored to join them.

I already have the following query:

```
select 
    recipeproducts.recipeID, 
    recipes.recipeName, 
    recipeproducts.productID, 
    products.productName, 
    products.quantity AS perverpakking, 
    recipeproducts.productQuantity AS nodig 
FROM 
    recipeproducts, 
    recipes, 
    products 
WHERE 
    recipeproducts.recipeID = recipes.recipeID AND
    recipeproducts.productID = products.productID
```

I want to only get (example number) 3 RANDOM recipes, but with all according products.

The rest of the project is based on PHP

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is so sad that you learned to use SQL with commas in the `FROM` clause.  You really should be using proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.

To do what you want, sample the recipes before joining:

```
select r.recipeID, r.recipeName, p.productID, p.productName,
       p.quantity AS perverpakking, rp.productQuantity AS nodig
FROM (SELECT r.*
      FROM recipes r
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 3
     ) r JOIN
     recipeproducts rp
     ON rp.recipeID = r.recipeID JOIN
     products p
     ON rp.productID = p.productID;
```

This assumes that all recipes have at least one product.

Comment: This helped me very much.

Comment: It does not work completely. It gives an Unknown column at p.productQuantity.